# How can I make this code smaller, without 3 loops? I should find 3 students with the smallest marks

Tags: c

I have to make my lab))
In general, I should find the index of three students with the smallest rating points.
How I can do it without three loops? Just by one.
In this function, I use structures and output arguments.

```
int addDelateThree(stud** pListHead, int* Imin, int* Jmin, int* Cmin) {
    stud* pTemp = pListHead;
    stud* SpTemp = pListHead;
    stud* TpTemp = pListHead;
    int check = 0;
    double min1 = pTemp->madian;
    double min2 = SpTemp->madian;
    double min3 = pTemp->median;

    int i = 0;
    while (pTemp != NULL) {
        if (min1 > pTemp->madian) {
            min1 = pTemp->madian;
            *Imin = i;
        }
        i++;
        pTemp = pTemp->next;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (SpTemp != NULL) {
        if (min2 > SpTemp->madian && i != *Imin) {
            min2 = SpTemp->madian;
            *Jmin = i;
        }
        i++;
        SpTemp = SpTemp->next;
    }

    i = 0;

    while (TpTemp != NULL) {
        if (min3 > TpTemp->madian && i != *Imin && i != *Jmin) {
            min3 = TpTemp->madian;
            *Cmin = i;
        }
        i++;
        TpTemp = TpTemp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *technical problem* you're having?

Comment: Sort the data and select the three smallest values from the sorted list?

Comment: Your function is defined to return an `int` but does not return any value.  Change its return type to `void`.

Comment: do it with pencil and paper first, then translate it to a program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a list of 3 `stud *`.  Initialize all to point to a dummy record whose  `.madian = INFINTY;`
2. Walk the linked list once.

   Compare node's `.madian` to `list[2]->madian`.  If `<=`, adjust list of 3 with new minimal `.madian`.  This may involve several compares as code compares 1st the greatest min value, then next greatest min and finally the least value.
3. Report result.

O(n) solution.